# Drupal translator only translating admin

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, translation, drupal-modules

I have a drupal site that I am working on and I am trying to figure out why I'm not able to translate the actual page content. I have a language selector on the main page and whenever you click a language it WILL change the language for the Admin-Menu but nothing else. The actual page contents remain in english.

I don't want to create individual/separate pages for each language as there will be 50+ pages and about 16 different languages. Where would I go to enable the translation of the actual content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that you have to create an individual page for each language. Site translation will only take care of static text across the site (Like: labels, buttons, etc).

Here's a [tutorial for Building a multi-language site](http://drupal.org/node/275705) in drupal.

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you (or anyone) tell me why that is? If they're able to change the interface, how come they can't change the actual content? 

Also, I'm waiting to mark it as answered to see if anyone else has any information regarding a possible work around or anything.

Comment: Because the nodes are flexible. They can have unlimited number of fields, some fields can contain HTML and CSS (in case of wysiwyg editors), nodes have revisions, go through many hooks, etc. So it's literally impossible to automate the translation or make a single table responsible for delivering the translated version.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It's unfortunate but understandable. Thank you again.